# Somebody explain me Html.DropDown and it's dearest friend SelectList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, selectlist

If you check my earlier questions you may have noticed I just don't get the SelectList and Html.DropDown(). I find it intrigueing that I seem to be the only one in this. So maybe I should try to change my mindset or maybe there are things I don't know that will clear this all up. I really love the whole MVC framework, but SelectList just doesn't want to fit in my head. So here's my list:

**SelectList**

- Why can't I set the selected value after instantiation
- Why can't I set selectedValue by index of items
- Why is the selectedvalue sometimes a string, sometimes the class I put into it and sometimes a ListItem
- Why are the items only accesible through GetItems()
- Why don't the types of selectedItem and the listItems match?
- Why are the items you put in the list converted to listItem and the selectedItem not?
- Why can't I get the count of the items without usint the GetItems() method

**Html.DropDownList()**

- Why doesn't modelbinding work with it
- Why is there no behaviour for defaulting selection when there's only one option
- Why doesn't making an item SelectedValue in the source selectLIst make it the marked item

Before ppl suggest me to write my own:
Since this will be shipped with the MVC product, I would rather have the offical support for a basic controll then to roll my own and have all the troubles that come with it.

Answer (score 3):

I feel your pain.  Forgive the shameless plug, but you might look into [MvcFluentHtml](http://lunaverse.wordpress.com/2008/11/24/mvcfluenthtml-fluent-html-interface-for-ms-mvc/).  You can still use SelectList and MultiSelectList, but you have several other choices.  Should work fine with binders.

Comment: didn't check this qtion out for a while. I'll have a look at the lib. Thx

Answer (score 2):

Likewise, I have had a number of bugbears with the HTML Helpers but none more so than SelectList. To add to the list of complaints I would like to know why SelectList does not accept (or is not able to handle) generic `IEnumerable<T>`. Again, you could cludge together your own implementation but `IEnumerable<T>` would enable quite a lot of handy functionality (such as direct support for LINQ/Entity Framework) and I feel should be provided.

MvcFluentHtml (now part of [MvcContrib](http://www.codeplex.com/MVCContrib)) looks like a nice addition though.

Comment: what other helpers lack in your opinion. I feel that with the latest drop they are quite what I expected (save for dropdown)

Answer (score 2):

I understand the majority of your questions, and strangely enough, I have not come across any problems as yet! However I may be using it exactly how the MVC developers intended me too and haven't needed to venture too much outside the box!

But hopefully to help you a little, here is an example of how I use SelectList and the properties I set:

`<%= Html.DropDownList("Module.Status", new SelectList(ViewData.Model.Statuses, "ID", "Name", ((int)ViewData.Model.Module.Status)), new {tabindex = 1, title = "Status"})` %>

and in my controller action I use a ModelBinder (you were saying this doesn't work? not sure what problems you're encountering there, mine is going fine.)

```
public ActionResult Save(int? id, [Bind(Prefix = "Module", 
            Include = "Name,Description,Status")] Module module)
```

Then status can be accessed, in my case by "`module.Status`".

Comment: I create the selectlist in my controller rather then in my view. Maybe indeed, this is what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: To avoid cluttered code, I want to keep my view code as clean as possible. I just started from the thought that I should keep all clutter out of my view to keep it as readable as possible.
<%Html.DropDownList("Statuses")%> does look much neater then your example code. But it doesn't do the job :(

Comment: The SelectList is view concept - not intended for use in the model. it should therfore not be in the controller. It seems like a generic list, but it really isnt.